# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gitlab' using Poetry in Python

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a python script which is giving me this error while running it. I'm using Poetry to install the packages.

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.1
$ python scripts/commons/sdlc_helper/mr_opening/create_schedule_pipeline.py --project_id ${CI_PROJECT_ID} --gl_token ${GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN} --source_branch ${SOURCE_BRANCH} --target_branch ${TARGET_BRANCH}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/internal/fd/fd-ci-config/commons/scripts/commons/sdlc_helper/mr_opening/create_schedule_pipeline.py", line 6, in <module>
    import gitlab
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gitlab'
```

The python script is at this path scripts/commons/sdlc_helper/mr_opening/create_schedule_pipeline.py and `pyproject.toml` file is at scripts folder with following configuration:-

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "scripts"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""    
packages = [{include = "test"}]
include = ["/**/*"]
readme = "README.md"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "self-hosted"
url = "http://nexus.xxxx.net/repository/pypi-hosted/simple"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.7.4,<4.0"
pytz = "^2022.1"
PyYAML = "^6.0"
dnspython = "^2.3.0"
ldap3 = "^2.9.1"
gssapi = "^1.8.2"
python-gitlab = "^3.15.0"
Jinja2 = "^3.1.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
create-schedule-pipeline = "commons.sdlc_helper.mr_opening.create_schedule_pipeline:main"
open-mr-automatically = "commons.sdlc_helper.mr_opening.open_mr_automatically:main"
```

May I know where is the problem so that I can take care of such issues going forward, thanks

Comment: Did you run `poetry install` first? Did you try running your script using `poetry run python your_script.py`?

Comment: I am unsure of the env you are running on, however: "never install poetry into the environment that should be managed by poetry. There's a good chance that otherwise dependencies needed by poetry itself gets removed or updated/downgrade when installing a project by poetry. Instead use the official installer or pipx." - [Answer from @finswimmer](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4493)